# Is it more standard to use subfig or subcaption package with beamer?

Tags: beamer, captions, subfloats

Suppose I'm making a `beamer` presentation and I want to have a figure with some subfigures (each of which shows an image).

Is it more standard/popular to use the `subfig` package or the `caption` and `subcaption` packages for this purpose?

What are the exact include statements I should use to include the appropriate packages?  I want to make sure I get the optional parameters correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

From version `caption.sty 2015/09/17 v3.3-111 Customizing captions (AR)` `subcaption` and `caption` are compatible with `beamer`, so you can use either `subcaption` or `subfig`. For older versions of `caption`, read below.

## Initial answer (old versions of `caption`)

If you *really* need subfigures in a presentation, with `beamer` you should use `subfig`. `subcaption` and `beamer` are not compatible.

This

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

gives the error

```
! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly
(caption)                in compatibility mode.
```

which forces you to load caption with compatibility=false:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and the `caption` package author says about this option:

> But please note that using this option is neither recommended nor
>   supported since unwanted side-effects or even errors could occur
>   afterwards. (For that reason you will get a warning about this.)

Load `subfig` with the `caption=false` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Since internally `subfig` requires the `caption` package; using the `caption=false` option prevents `caption` from taking (ot attempting to take) control over captions in `beamer`.

Comment: Thank you, and are there any special options that I must use in my include statement for subfig (when using beamer)?  Also, it sounds like you discourage the use of subfigures in a presentation -- what do you think is a better approach?

Comment: @littleO You're welcome. Yes, at least you should use `caption=false`; I just added this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, what does the caption=false option do (out of curiosity)?

Comment: @littleO Internally `subfig` requires the `caption` package; using `caption=false` prevents `caption` from taking  (ot attempting to take) control over captions in `beamer`.

Comment: @littleO In a presentation for let's say a Congress, time is of the escence and you should focus on more important matters; it really doesn't matter to the audience if you have numbered subcaptions and cross-references (in fact, you shouldn't have them), and `minipage`s or `columns` environments are more than enough. Perhaps a longer presentation (for a lectour course) might merit the use of real subfigures.

Comment: Actually the caption and subcaption package should be compatible with beamer, see also caption doc. Unfortunately the support is broken for about 2 years now (after a change in beamer regarding \caption) and nobody told me... :-(   However, I just fixed that: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/21/ (I will upload a new version to CTAN on Sunday.)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Ah, that is good news! I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Answer updated.

Comment: @littleO There's new information that might be of interest for you. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Gonzalo Thanks.  I think this is an important update that other people will care about too.  @AxelSommerfeldt Would you mind posting an answer that contains a MWE to show how subcaption would typically be used with beamer?  In particular, should any special options be used?

Comment: @littleO No need to load it in any special way. `\usepackage{subcaption}`; read Section **5.3 beamer** of the `caption` package documentation for some features when using `caption`+`beamer`.